# General approach to fault analysis for a rechargeable battery

Tags: circuit-analysis, battery-charging, fault

I have a pair of over ear headphones which work fine except that the rechargeable battery in the circuit is no longer charging. I have replaced the battery, but the new battery also does not receive any new charge.

The circuit design necessarily spans a number of complex boards including dual noise cancelling arrays, a Bluetooth module and a wired connection through the head band from the ear which receives the 5V charge, to the other ear which contains the rechargeable 3.7V battery. Through the use of a multimeter I am able to confirm the 5V charge reaches the main board, but cannot figure out why it doesn't seem to reach the battery.

Is there a general investigative approach one can take to such a problem in order to isolate the cause, or is it necessary to know and understand the details of the (complex, at least for me) circuit design in order to fix the problem? As my question probably indicates, I have some very basic electronics knowledge, basic being the important word!

Comment: like writing a detective novel; start with the ending. What's the battery voltage? What about the bt module, it should be at 3.3v. knock out as many known values as you can to segment the areas of concern. keep in mind that things can fail invisible inside a blob or a chip, so a dmm probe might not find the fault.